# Regarding superior of periodic functions.

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $\ f:[0,1] \rightarrow R$, and $f(x) = \lim\sup\cos\ (2\pi nx)$.  How I am going to describe the function $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Mary, you just need to prove your function is constant!

Comment: @ John, that's a good hint. Also had that in mind